# Search for string in text file in-between two key words

Tags: python, search

I have a program written in Python that prints a code as such:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
ArtistName = "FUN.";
SongName = "We Are Young";
</script>
```

I have tried writing a script in awk to allow me to save the ArtistName and SongName as variable but can't see to figure it out. Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: You have a Python program to generate some JS code which afterwards, you'd like to extract the values of `ArtistName` and `SongName` from ? Is the example above literally the data, or could it appear with variations inside full blown HTML pages?

Comment: That is the exact source code that will be printed every time just with the actual ArtistName and SongName changing. I was thinking about possible creating an if statement that would start the the string matches "ArtistName" and print each character until i hit a semi colon. I do not know if this would work though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is consistent enough, you might be able to get away using a regex (as long as you don't have names with an `"` etc...), eg:

```
text="""<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
ArtistName = "FUN.";
SongName = "We Are Young";
</script> """

import re

print dict(re.findall(r'((?:Artist|Song)Name)\s=\s"([^"]*)"', text))
# {'ArtistName': 'FUN.', 'SongName': 'We Are Young'}
```

Comment: That works great, is there any way though to just have the output be "FUN., We are Young" or something along those lines?

Comment: @ConnorMartinuzzi assuming they're in the right order - Artist then Song name, and there's just the two - you can adapt the above to be `print ', '.join(re.findall(r'(?:Artist|Song)Name\s=\s"([^"]*)"', text)) # FUN., We Are Young`

Comment: got it. So must i enter a string for this to work or could i enter a text file?

Comment: @ConnorMartinuzzi read the file into a string if you want... `with open('yourfile') as fin: text = fin.read()` or similar

Answer (score 0):

You can save `ArtistName` and `SongName` as keys in a dictionary using regular expressions if you want.

Here are some links to explanations of regular expressions: [Python Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm)

```
import re

s = #string you're parsing

regex = re.compile(r'\w+ = \".*\";')
matches = regex.findall(s)

dict1 = {}
for m in matches:

    elems = m.split(" = ")

    dict1[str(elems[0])] = elems[len(elems) - 1].strip(';')


print (dict1['ArtistName'])
print (dict1['SongName'])
```

Output (using your example string):

```
'"FUN."'
'"We Are Young"'
```